# How to show error message on previous page?

Tags: php

I want to show an error on the same as page as my form. My form is going to another page and then processing and returning the result. How can I show the error on the previous page?

```
if($_POST['btnManage']=="Signup"){
    $objCustomer->Email=$_POST['txtEmail'];
    $objCustomer->Password=$_POST['txtPassword'];
    $Status=$objCustomer->Signup();
    if($Status>0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['Email']=$objCustomer->Email;
        header("Location:../index.php");
    } else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind error you want?

Comment: You send the form by means of an AJAX request in background instead of a standard http form post. That way your page does not go through a full reload but stays in the browser and you can inject the answer you get back upon the form submission (the error) to the already loaded page. There are many examples for that to be found online.

Comment: can you provide any example. that would b great help. thanks

Comment: You can put the error message in the query string, in session, etc. and redirect the user to the desired page, then use that value to display a message on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Going with what you have using $_SESSION, you can set eorr in the session.

```
else
{
$_SESSION["eorr"] = "message_here";
header("Location:../{form_page_here}");
}
```

Then on the page that has your form, do a check if $_SESSION["eorr"] is set an display the message. You would also need to `unset($_SESSION["eorr"];` after it is displayed so it is removed if you do not need to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

Three step to handle the error

step1: define your error code and error message

```
define('SYSTEM_ERROR',1000);
define('SYSTEM_ERROR_MESSAGE','your error message');
```

step2: put the current error code to the reference url as a parameter

```
http://localhost?error=1000
```

step3: redirect to the reference page ,handle the error code and show to the page

```
$error = $_GET['error'];
if($error ==SYSTEM_ERROR){
     $errorMessage = SYSTEM_ERROR_MESSAGE;
}
//show the $errorMessage
```